# Hide and Unhide a field based on another field value

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a form in Access 2010. this form included a combo box named "Type" related to a field in a table that named "Type". another combo box that is "Car_1" is related to a field in the same table that named "Car_1"
I want when the "Type" combo box is empty (null) then the combo box Car_1 should be invisible.

I wrote a code but does not work. actually, the "Car_1" combo box is visible always!

the code is:

```
Private Sub Form_Current()

If Me.Type.Value = "" Then

    Me.Car_1.Visible = False

Else

    Me.Car_1.Visible = True

End If

End Sub
```

any advice is appropriate ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you're not testing if `Me.Type.Value` is `Null`, you're testing if it's a zero-length string. Test if it's `Null` instead:

```
Private Sub Form_Current()

    If IsNull(Me.Type.Value) Then

        Me.Car_1.Visible = False

    Else

        Me.Car_1.Visible = True

    End If

End Sub
```

Or account for both `Null` and a zero-length string:

```
Private Sub Form_Current()

    If Me.Type.Value & vbNullString = vbNullString Then

        Me.Car_1.Visible = False

    Else

        Me.Car_1.Visible = True

    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You could reduce it to a one-liner:

```
Private Sub Form_Current()

    Me!Car_1.Visible = Not IsNull(Me!Type.Value)

End Sub
```